# How to estimate sigma in scipy.optimize.curve_fit for real world data?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to estimate the parameters of an ore body which exhibits self potential using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. Whenever I use a synthetic data without noise, the parameters are accurately predicted. The moment I add gaussian white noise to it, the parameters have huge errors. I understand that `curve_fit` has an argument to input the errors as `sigma` and when I input the noise values in, it works. My question is how will I estimate the sigma value in the real world where I won't have the noise values of the individual points?

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = pd.read_csv('at_5.csv', index_col='index')
x_data = np.array(data['x'])
y_data = np.array(data['v(x)'])

# adding errors
signal_power = np.mean(y_data**2)
def awgn(signal, desired_snr, signal_power):
    # Calculate the noise power based on the desired SNR and signal power
    noise_power = signal_power / (10 ** (desired_snr / 10))

    # Generate the noise with the calculated power
    noise = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(noise_power), len(signal))

    # Add the noise to the original signal
    noisy_signal = signal + noise
    print(noise)

    return noisy_signal, noise


noisy_signal, noise = awgn(y_data, desired_snr=33, signal_power=signal_power)

# defining curve function
def log_function(x, k, h, xo, a, ang, gamma):
    return k * np.log(((((x - xo) - a * math.cos(ang)) ** 2) + (h - a * math.sin(ang)) ** 2) /
                        ((((x - xo) + a * math.cos(ang)) ** 2) + (h + a * math.sin(ang)) ** 2)) + gamma

guess = [75, 150, 550, 45, math.radians(30), 0]  # initial guesses

guesser = log_function(x_data, guess[0], guess[1], guess[2], guess[3], guess[4], guess[5])

sig = 1/noisy_signal # trying to implement a solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704940/using-the-absolute-sigma-parameter-in-scipy-optimize-curve-fit

popt, cov = curve_fit(log_function, x_data, noisy_signal, p0=guess, maxfev=10000, method='lm', sigma=sig, absolute_sigma=False)

a, b, c, d, e, f = popt

y_model = log_function(x_data, a, b, c, d, e, f) # curve from obtained parameters


err = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 = err
print(f'''K = {a} +- {a1}, \nh = {b} +- {b1}, \nXo = {c} +- {c1}, \na = {d} +- {d1}, \nangle = {math.degrees(e)} +- {math.degrees(e1)} \nand gamma = {f} +- {f1}''')

# plotting data

plt.scatter(x_data, noisy_signal, s=5, c='blue')
plt.plot(x_data, guesser, color='green')
plt.plot(x_data, y_model, color='red')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('V(X)')
plt.legend(['Data', 'Guess', 'Matched Data'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

I tried using an average sigma value for all the data, still the errors were in 3 digits. I have also tried to add sigma as given in the Stack Overflow post [Using the absolute_sigma parameter in scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704940/using-the-absolute-sigma-parameter-in-scipy-optimize-curve-fit) with no luck.

Comment: `My question is how will I estimate the sigma value in the real world where I won't have the noise values of the individual points?` If you know that certain points are measured less accurately than other points, then you can give high sigma values to uncertain points, and low sigma values to certain points. If you have no idea which points are uncertain, then you can skip providing sigma. Providing a constant sigma is exactly the same as not providing sigma at all.